# Create an unique ID number after submit form

Tags: php, database

I'm still learning PHP and MySQL and need to create a unique number in Wordpress site (as a order number ID) every time, when user fill and submit "order" form from frontend and save it to database. Next submit will create a number+1. Website is not running on Woocommerce. No cart, checkout, products...

Thanks for help! :)

Answer (score 0):

in order to do this use

```
 AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
```

while you define your table. Your table should be something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `order` (
            `order_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
            `user_group_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
            `status` BIT,
            `meta` VARCHAR ( 255 ),
            `value` TEXT,
            `update_time` TIMESTAMP
            )DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
```

remember that you could change other columns, the important one is `order_id` which is auto increment

Answer (score -1):

You can get the unique ID number by using the merge tag {submission:sequence}. It allows you to get the submission number of the current user’s submission.It only populates after the submission data has been saved to the database.